# TCP socket randomly throwing SocketException: sendto failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP socket in my application. Its only function at this moment is periodically sending a packet to keep alive the connection with the server. After a successful connection, my loop is:

```
while (running) {
    outputStream.write(0x00);
    outputStream.flush();
    Thread.sleep(5000 + random.nextInt(5000));
}
```

However, sometimes and apparently randomly, the `write` method throws the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:542)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:511)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:500)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.-wrap1(PlainSocketImpl.java)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
    at libcore.io.Streams.writeSingleByte(Streams.java:53)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:262)
    at myapp.Service$TCPClient.run(Service.java:174)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:211)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:278)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:509)
... 8 more
```

I am not able to replicate the error, it just happens sometimes. At the next iteration, the packet is successfully sent, and received by the server. The connection is always established.

What could be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: This is a bug in the Android platform.

Comment: @EJP Could you provide some source? I have not seen anything in the AOSP issue tracker.